# In Nginx, sub-domain redirects to a wrong sub-domain in SSL

Tags: nginx, cname-record

I created on my webhosting a CNAME to redirect :

- test.example.org to test.example.com
- prod.example.org to prod.example.com

Now I try to redirect http to https for prod & test and then to my app

```
    server  {
        listen 80;
        server_name prod.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    server  {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
# TEST
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.example.com;

        # SSL
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate       fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key   privkey.pem;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
# PROD
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name prod.example.com;

        # SSL
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate       fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key   privkey.pem;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8182;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

The problem with the configuration above, if i type **test**.example.**org** i'm redirect to **prod**.example.**com**

Comment: Replace `listen 80;` to `listen 443 ssl;` in SSL-enabled blocks

Comment: my bad, i have done an error while writing this post.
Currently i have : 
listen 443 ssl;

Comment: You should fix code in post

Answer (score 1):

You need to define server blocks for the `.example.org` domains in your nginx setup. A CNAME mapping only maps one domain name to another, and therefore the client sees that the IP address for `test.example.org` is the one running your nginx server.

So, clients sends a request with Host header / SSL domain name of `test.example.org`. Since there is no matching `server` block in nginx, it uses the default one, which in this case is the last block defined. This is because you have no `default_server` set up.